# how to find out which activity had started intent ,in my activity in android

Tags: android, facebook

i am trying to get the intent,which activity had started
 the intent, i am trying facebook integration with my app,in which i
 want to know who have called my activity is the call from facebook or
 withen my app, suppose i have 3 activity a,b & c, a call b c call b
 facebook calls b here in activity i want to detect who have started
 activity b how to get this, i googled it but no use please share yours
 views on this or any refrence thank you

Comment: Are you talking about deep linking from the Facebook app to your app, or just Facebook SDK integration (with login)?

Answer (score 2):

you should maintain a variable for an activity and send it with intent as extra along with intent, and check when you start activity and check that common extra variable.

Like Intent.putExtra("From", "a");

and get data and check it from where it comes

Comment: yes if i use putextra(), then its ok while starting activity withn my app,but how to detect if the call is from facebook

Comment: from facebook how you start an activity

Comment: in facebook while providing packagename we have to give the starting activity ,so that from facebook search the activity will start

Comment: while providing packagename we have to give class name as well,so that in from facebook that class will start,check this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/link-to-your-native-app/#step7

Comment: you can also check where extra value is not available  that means it comes from facebook. you also check like this. if(extra.has(From)!=null)...

Answer (score 0):

For deep linking, why not just use an Activity class that's specific to Facebook?

Since you're configuring the class name in your app settings, just use a class that's something like: FacebookDeepLinkActivity, and from there, you can start another activity in your app if you want. This way, you know exactly which links came from Facebook.

Comment: ok thanx @ming,i have one another ? if i am not using deep linking ,than what to do in such case

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your other scenario. If you're not deep linking, then what are you trying to do?

Comment: ok fine, i want when user search on facebook for my app, then the facebook search display my app name,after clicking on my app,it should open my app if it is installed on user device else it should redirect to google play, i want to achieve the above conditions so i am little bit confused, what to do in such a case,thanx

Comment: It should do that already, are you saying it doesn't? And if not, what is the behavior you're seeing?